# Two choices when a town is under attack

Tags: die2nite

When the town is under attack, one gets two options like:

- Pray for your life
- Wail like a banshee

Does your choice (or even choosing at all) make any difference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. There is absolutely no benefit or negative impact to clicking those buttons. Their sole purpose is to pass time thinking of amusing ways your character might be reacting to the zombies attacking your town.

Answer (score 0):

Choosing changes absolutely nothing; these options do not affect your survival at all.